# Facebook 'like' - redirect path to the wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-like

I'm trying to get the Facebook 'like' button working on a site that has some job listings for different companies - each company can have various incoming links (such as http://apply.co/xentrix_studios or http://apply.co/xentrix_studios/facebook that are redirected to a general list of that company's jobs at http://apply.co/jobs.

Here's the Facebook debug for one of the links: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=apply.co%2Fxentrix_studios

**Look at the redirect path.** Facebook is going from /xentrix_studios to /jobs to the root at http://apply.co. So, the readings it's giving us are for the root url, which is obviously not what we want.

How can I get Facebook to just *stay* at the right page after it follows the incoming link?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is returning a 301 redirect for that URL. If you want Facebook to treat a URL as being a real URL, it needs to return content including the meta tags that tell Facebook what image/description/etc to use.
I checked this with

> curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i "http://apply.co/xentrix_studios"

The response was

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 10:10:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://apply.co/jobs
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Set-Cookie: _rubyjobs_session=BAh7DUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZjk3NDk0YTI0ZGIxMDNhODA2YWE0YTgxOGUyNmZkNTNJIg5qb2JfcmVhZHMGOwBGWwBJIg5qb2Jfc2F2ZXMGOwBGWwBJIhB2aXNpdF9jb3VudAY7AEZbAEkiCXBhdGgGOwBGSSIUeGVudHJpeF9zdHVkaW9zBjsAVEkiDGxpbmtfaWQGOwBGaQBJIghhbGkGOwBGaQKbAUkiCHRsaQY7AEZpAnUE--996d80cb1a2b170c46b6e8f09dcef447fb882917; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 0.036089
Content-Length: 86
X-Varnish: 1415265483
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://apply.co/jobs">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: The confusion I'm having is this: when I go to apply.co/xentrix_studios in my browser, it ends up at apply.co/jobs, which does have the FB tags I want! This (one) redirect is intended, but FB seems to be going to the root instead.

Comment: Sorry, i see now.. the problem is this meta tag: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.apply.co/" />` - the og:url should point to the canonical url for the content, in this case you're redirecting facebook back to the root of the domain

Comment: Hi Igy - I've changed the code and I'm still getting issues. Try debugging this link: http://apply.co/apply/46?key=480dd37111bf183e7136656bfc4d9349